# Is sync.Mutex.Lock a FIFO?

Tags: go, concurrency

If many threads lock on a [mutex](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) do they queue up in a FIFO order or is there some amount of randomness to which goroutine acquires the lock when it becomes unlocked?

Comment: Relying on the order of execution of concurrent operations is a design flaw. If you find yourself in a situation where you think this is necessary, consider another design approach - for example, putting work in a channel (which *is* a FIFO queue) so you can worry about the order execution of *work* rather than the order of execution of *threads*.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the question was more about if it was the right tool for order which reading the source proves it is not.

Comment: @Adrian FWIW channels suffer the same problem you have no guarantee that goroutines will push onto a channel in the order that they block. Same applies to popping.

Comment: You're missing the point. You shouldn't care what order the goroutines execute in. If you care what order a *task* is executed in, wrap it in a struct and put it on a channel. Messages are read from channels FIFO, and it doesn't matter which of a pool of identical workers picks up the message. Tasks will still be executed in the order they're queued.

Answer (score 9):

From the [source](https://golang.org/src/sync/mutex.go?s=765:813#L42):

```
// Mutex fairness.
//
// Mutex can be in 2 modes of operations: normal and starvation.
// In normal mode waiters are queued in FIFO order, but a woken up waiter
// does not own the mutex and competes with new arriving goroutines over
// the ownership. New arriving goroutines have an advantage -- they are
// already running on CPU and there can be lots of them, so a woken up
// waiter has good chances of losing. In such case it is queued at front
// of the wait queue. If a waiter fails to acquire the mutex for more than 1ms,
// it switches mutex to the starvation mode.
//
// In starvation mode ownership of the mutex is directly handed off from
// the unlocking goroutine to the waiter at the front of the queue.
// New arriving goroutines don't try to acquire the mutex even if it appears
// to be unlocked, and don't try to spin. Instead they queue themselves at
// the tail of the wait queue.
//
// If a waiter receives ownership of the mutex and sees that either
// (1) it is the last waiter in the queue, or (2) it waited for less than 1 ms,
// it switches mutex back to normal operation mode.
//
// Normal mode has considerably better performance as a goroutine can acquire
// a mutex several times in a row even if there are blocked waiters.
// Starvation mode is important to prevent pathological cases of tail latency.
```

So guaranteeing order across threads cannot be achieved by simply using a mutex.